# Spring Transactional cannot read updated value

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-data, spring-transactions

I am using Spring and have following junit-method:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:TestProject-spring-test.xml" })
@Transactional
public abstract class BaseTest {
[...]

    @Test
    public void testSaveLoadedObject() {
        SubTestModel st = modelService.load(subTestPk);

        st.setSimpleObject("testString");

        modelService.save(st);

        //now reload the object to ensure that everything has been saved correctly
        st = modelService.load(st.getId());
        s+= "\n#3 afterLoad:   " + st.getSimpleObject();

        //fails:
        Assert.assertTrue(st.getSimpleObject().equals("testString"));
    }
}
```

**ModelService-Method:**

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate db;

@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void save(final ItemModel model, String newValue) {
    db.update("UPDATE table SET column=? WHERE id=?", new Object[] { newValue, model.getId() });
}

@Override
public <T extends AbstractItemModel> T load(final int id) {
    ...  
    DAO.loadValue(...)
}
```

**DAO-Method:**
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate db;

```
@Override
public <T> T loadValue(final AbstractItemModel model, final String columnName) {
        final String sql = "SELECT column FROM table WHERE id=" + model.getId();

    Object plain = db.queryForObject(sql, new RowMapper<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object mapRow(ResultSet r, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            return r.getObject(columnName);
        }
    });

    return plain;

}
```

**Following happens:**

original value:
[image]

*the new Value is stored in the DB (visible when setting "SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED") in mysql.*

getSimpleObject-Value in DB = "testString"
[image]

*but when the load method is called, it gets the "old" (=value before save) value *

getSimpleObject-Value in Debugger = "simpleObjectValue"

**Why cannot the recently saved value (in the same transaction and method) can be read by the load-method?**

You see that it doesn't create a new transaction. even setting the isolation level with "@Transaction(isolation=READ_UNCOMMITTED)" over the whole test-method doesn't help

can anyone solve this mystery?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It all depends on what the load and save methods do. The code matters.

Comment: hi. save executes a jdbctemplate."INSERT INTO ...". load executes a jdbctemplate..queryForObject(...)

Comment: Do you need further information?

Answer (score 0):

Change propagation to REQUIRES_NEW on your save method (to commit the change on the db and open a new transaction).

Or even better, add flush call after saving in your test (it is better because you will not change your code just to adapt it to your integration test).

Comment: are the changes made by the test-method still rolled back after it finished? because that is required, otherwise i would fill it up with test data...
I need something like "execute some methods which create and checks data and after finish roll it all back"--> @transactional

Comment: When I don't use spring's transaction management, and manually insert and select it by jdbc in the same transaction, it works fine. so something must be wrong here...